# Is there a way to import Trello boards into Todoist?

Tags: trello, import

It doesn't look like there's an officially supported way to do this.  Is anyone aware of any other way to import Trello boards into Todoist?

Update:

Got this link from Todoist support:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Rl_CLGY_3o

Apparently you can import 200 tasks per project in this manner.  I will report back if I end up using it.

Comment: Can you add a summary of what's in the video as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://todoport.com - I built it for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, @drcharris!  I saw this in a response in the Todoist forum.  It looks like it doesn't attempt to recreate the Trello board structure within Todoist, is that correct?  For example, it takes a single Trello board, flattens it, and then creates Todoist tasks out of them?

Comment: Could you summarize how the features of this product answer the OP's question, as mentioned by @pnuts?  Thanks for disclosing your affiliation.

Comment: As detailed in the help page it gives limited support and won't migrate notes, comments, stickers, or attachments. For basic structure however, it will convert Trello lists into Todoist projects, since that is the highest-level grouping of tasks that Todoist has and I think is the closest to a Trello list semantically.
Cards are converted into Todoist tasks.
Checklists are converted into tasks with subtasks, with a special case for where there is a single checklist